# Geoserver layers access

Tags: geoserver, layers, security

I need to change the layer visibility for users in my application. Layers are served by OL 3 by a wms/wfs request. The problem is that when I change the accessibility for users, banning someone to see layers, they still have access to them  as long as they don't log out or close the browser.

Comment: What if you restart the service?

Comment: How are you banning them from seeing the layer?

Comment: I am simply giving them (or removing) specific role for reading/writing the layers. I am doing it by the web administrator interface.I thought it was a cache problem and I tried to check the Enable Data Security option in the caching default. This, if I understood good, should check the user permission everytime the service is called, but nothing changed. I really appreciate your answers. Federico

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution. I had to clean the cache for making  the update work immediately. I could not rebuild the whole application so, I created a small OWS like explained [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/ows-services/implementing.html), to clean the authentication  cache, I then added it to the WEB-INF/lib folder.
You should have any other solutions I would appreciate. Thanks

Federico